# Linux/OSX Clock Resolution with millisecond accuracy?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, time

On Windows, I can call QueryPerformanceCounter to get high resolution data points, but this method call is affected by issues with the BIOS, multi-core CPUs, and some AMD chips.  I can call timeBeginPeriod to increase the system clock resolution in Windows down to 1ms (instead of the standard ~15ms) which means that I can use just call timeGetTime and get the time in the clock resolution that I've specified.

So!  On OSX/Linux, what C++ clock resolutions should I expect?  Can I get 1ms resolution similar to Windows?  Since I'm doing real time media, I want this clock resolution to be as low as possible: can I change this value in the kernel (like in Windows with timeBeginPeriod)?  This is a high performance application, so I want getting the current time to be a fast function call.  And I'd like to know if the clock generally drifts or what weird problems I can expect.

Thanks!
Brett

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using C++11 you can use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) which should give you as high a resolution clock as the system offers. To get a millisecond duration you would do

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock my_clock;

my_clock::time_point start = my_clock::now();

// Do stuff

my_clock::time_point end = my_clock::now();

std::chrono::milliseconds ms_duration = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
```

If you aren't using C++11 then the [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html) function works in OSX and most linux distributions. It gives you the time since epoch in seconds and microseconds. The resolution is unspecified, but it should give you at least millisecond accuracy on any modern system.

Comment: Working on macOS, the gettimeofday() function was a solution for me. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to David's answer, if you can't use C++11, Boost's [Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html) classes can help you.

Comment: Hi , I have a similar kind of requirement . In windows I am using  timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod in my high performance application.  Now , what can be used in Linux for clock resolution of 1 ms as given by above two windows API's.  Does the above solution of using chrono:: high_resolution_clock works fine? or Is there any new solution  or workaround now to implement this in Linux .